# Yum update unable to find package, that is in repo list

Tags: centos7, yum

When trying to run `sudo yum update` I get

```
 --> Finished Dependency Resolution Error: Package: cinnamon-3.6.7-3.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
            Requires: caribou(x86-64)
            Removing: caribou-0.4.21-1.el7.x86_64 (@base)
                caribou(x86-64) = 0.4.21-1.el7
            Obsoleted By: gnome-shell-3.28.3-6.el7.x86_64 (base)
                Not found  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

Firts I assumed it might be a repo problem and would be fixed, but after a week I started investigating. When checking http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/ I can see a package [gnome-shell-3.28.3-6.el7.x86_64.rpm](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/gnome-shell-3.28.3-6.el7.x86_64.rpm).

This lead me to check my yum configuration and I changed `yum.repos.d` so that it uses the central mirror and idsabled the mirrorlist:

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

Afterwards I ran `sudo yum clean all` and `sudo yum update`, yet I still get the same error. What is wrong with my yum setup? Do I have to force yum to reread the configuration in another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is not that you have used the CentOS mirrorlist, and you can re-enable that.

The problem is that the Cinnamon desktop has been removed from EPEL as its package maintainer decided to stop maintaining it (long ago) and for several months no one stepped up to continue maintaining it.

You will need to remove the `cinnamon` package from your system to resolve the problem.

```
yum remove cinnamon
```

Comment: That leaves me with one question: why do I see a package in the linked repository, but yum does not find it, even when using yum search? (Less pressing, how do you know about this issue, is there something like the news section on the archlinux page?)

Comment: I just Googled it and found some chatter on the CentOS forum about it.